# Why should we use PuTTY if we have cmd?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, cmd.exe, putty

I believe that the command can do all what PuTTY does. For example with SSH, why should we use PuTTY instead of command?

Comment: I would have thought that your re-write of this question would have included the suggestion from the other site that this has nothing to do with cmd.exe.  [This page](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/windows-10-ssh-vs-putty/) might help you see why you would use ssh.exe over Putty or visa versa.  You should still edit your question to Why putty vs internal ssh client? (or something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by `cmd`, you actually mean OpenSSH `ssh` executed in `cmd`.

Both OpenSSH `ssh` and PuTTY are just two implementations of *SSH terminal client*. As with any other kind of applications, there are multiple implementations. Use the one that suit your needs. Both `ssh` and PuTTY have their advantages.